# Нелогичная подмена значений переменной

Tags: php, yii

Всю голову сломал, не понимаю, как так происходит. *PHP 5.4 Yii 1.1.15*

Есть вот такой контроллер:

```
class MyController extends CController {
    private $_modelUser;

    // для простоты понимания, перенёс это сюда
    public function test() {
        $modelTest = UserModule::user();
        $modelTest->profile->attributes = ['firstname'=>'gon']; // для проверки
    }

    public function loadUser($id = null) {
        if ($this->_modelUser === null) {
            $this->_modelUser = UserModule::user($id);
        }
        return $this->_modelUser;
    }
    public function actionEdit() {
        $model = $this->loadUser();

        $this->render('edit', [
            'model'   => $model,
            'profile' => $model->profile
        ]);
    }
}
```

В `UserModule::user` вытягиваются связанные таблицы user и profile вот так:

```
public static function user($id = null) {
        //...
        if (!self::$_user) {
            self::$_user = User::model()->with('profile')->findbyPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
        }
        return self::$_user;
    }
```

Как видно, я гружу данные пользователя и передаю в представление, а в представлении делаю вот так:

```
var_dump($profile->attributes);
$this->test();
var_dump($profile->attributes);
```

и получаю

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["firstname"]=> string(5) "Admin"}
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["firstname"]=> string(3) "gon"}
```

Вопрос: каким образом меняется переменная `$profile`? Нигде ничего по ссылке не передаю.
Не могу понять, как вообще она постфактум меняется без моего ведома.

Comment: Может, я чего-то не понимаю, но вы сами меняете её в функции test()

Comment: А что собственно Вас удивляет? 
У Вас же явно написан код, по присваиванию переменной нового значения: $modelTest->profile->attributes = ['firstname'=>'gon'];

Comment: @МаринаВоин и @MasterAlex, на самом деле, если вы могли заметить переменная $modelTest локальная и не выходит за рамки функции test()

Comment: объекты **всегда** передаются по ссылке в силу реализации

Comment: @frgs У Вас статичное свойство `self::$_user`, которое хранит состояние модели User, т.е. при каждом обращении `UserModule::user()`, возвращается один и тот же объект. Исправьте это, либо клонируйте `$profile`: `clone $profile`.

Comment: @romeo, спасибо Вам. Не знал про клонирование, как раз то, чего не мог найти.

Comment: @frgs, прочитай еще раз про ООП

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас статическое свойство `self::$_user`, которое хранит состояние модели `User`, т.е. при каждом обращении `UserModule::user()`, возвращается один и тот же объект. Исправьте это, либо клонируйте `$profile`:

```
$newProfile = clone $profile;
```

Comment: это работает, но насколько верно делать через клонирование? Мне видится это каким-то костылём.
Пробовал не через статический метод, без клонирования всё равно не работает.

Comment: Да, костыль. У Вас явный просчёт в реализации. Мало информации о том, что вы хотите конкретно. Вам необходимо менять модель `User`? Если нет, то можно `$profile` конвертировать в массив (`toArray()`, если не ошибаюсь) и далее изменять его. Либо возвращать каждый раз новую модель:

    public static function user($id = null) 
    {
      return User::model()->with('profile')->findbyPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    }

Только это не будет верным, ибо каждый раз когда вы дергаете `UserModule::user()`, будет производиться запрос к СУБД.

Comment: @romeo, я хотел в этом методе присвоить безопасные атрибуты, но жутко не понравился этот костыль, и всё переделал. Хотя сначала тоже пробовал в массив засунуть и клонировать, и, в качестве теста, делать каждый раз новые запросы, но всё выглядело очень некрасиво.
Но спасибо, в любом случае, а то сидел тупил, т.к. матчасть про ссылки из головы вылетела :)